# What's the name of this type of fabric pattern?

Tags: fabric

Does somebody know what's the name of this fabric pattern? In Spanish is *Estampado Búlgaro* but when I search *Bulgarian Pattern* on Google Images nothing even similar appear.

[image: pattern]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called "[paisley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paisley_(design))" in English.

> Paisley or paisley pattern is an ornamental design using the buta (Persian: بته‎) or boteh, a teardrop-shaped motif with a curved upper end. Of Persian origin,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paisley_(design)) paisley designs became very popular in the West in the 18th and 19th centuries, following imports of post-Mughal Empire versions of the design from India, especially in the form of Kashmir shawls, and were then imitated locally. Although the fig- or almond-like form is of Persian origin, its English name derives from the town of Paisley, in West Scotland, a centre for textiles where paisley designs were produced.

Comment: Any idea why the Búlgaro name is in there? There are lots of paisleys out there, are there named subgenera of paisley?

Comment: It might be that Paisley came to England from Bulgaria .. humm, no .. wikipedia says “Paisley or paisley pattern is an ornamental design using the buta (Persian: بته‎) or boteh, a teardrop-shaped motif with a curved upper end. Of Persian origin,[1] paisley designs became very popular in the West. Although the fig- or almond-like form is of Persian origin, its English name derives from the town of Paisley, in West Scotland, a centre for textiles where paisley designs were produced”

Answer (score -1):

this is the paisley pattern, originated in Persia and spreading to India. In Henna (drawing on hands and legs by henna ink), paisley is also a favourite pattern.

Comment: Hi Ailita! Just as a heads-up: your answer contains a lot of information that is already provided in the accepted answer. Please check out the [Tour](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/tour) and our [Help section](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help) to get yourself familiarized with the Stack Exchange platform. Welcome to Arts & Crafts!